# I want to export my Data in a Cell Array to an Excel file, as tidy as possible, without semi-colons for new rows

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, export, cell

I have a Cell Array of dimensions 2 by 40, and each cell contains a matrix of dimensions 3 by 3:

```
[3x3 double]    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double] ... [3x3 double]
[3x3 double]    [3x3 double]    [3x3 double] ... [3x3 double]
```

Now, I need to print this Cell Array and show it to my study group. Below is the detailed example of what I am trying to achieve.

Print should show each matrix in the cell clearly and separately, so that we can study it better, similar to this:

```
 [1 2 3]    [5 2 3] 
 [4 5 6]    [1 2 2]    ...
 [7 8 9]    [7 8 9]

 [5 2 3]    [4 5 6]   
 [3 5 6]    [7 2 9]    ...
 [7 1 9]    [5 2 3]
```

I tried converting Cell to Table, unfortunately this was untidy, as it showed each new row of matrices with semi-colons:

```
 [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

Also, I tried converting Cell to Double with:

```
 data = [cell{1,:};cell{2,:}];
```

resulting in 6 by 120 double, looking like this:

```
 1 2 3 5 2 3
 4 5 6 1 2 2    ...
 7 8 9 7 8 9
 5 2 3 2 5 6   
 3 5 6 7 2 9    ...
 7 1 9 5 2 3
```

I can export this to an Excel file, however you can see that it is still cumbersome. I can cut and paste the rows 4,5,6 and shift them below so that it looks like:

```
 1 2 3 5 2 3
 4 5 6 1 2 2    ...
 7 8 9 7 8 9

 5 2 3 2 5 6   
 3 5 6 7 2 9    ...
 7 1 9 5 2 3
```

however I still need to divide every other 3 columns, so that I can achieve what I want, which is very impractical:

```
 1 2 3  5 2 3
 4 5 6  1 2 2    ...
 7 8 9  7 8 9

 5 2 3  2 5 6   
 3 5 6  7 2 9    ...
 7 1 9  5 2 3
```

I would really appreciate your help on this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `celldisp` to display it?

Comment: I need to convert the data into something printable and easy to the eye, so that we can follow where the data goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a complex cell array like this, you can use `celldisp` to display the cell in an understandable way.

```
% Create some example data
D = arrayfun(@(x)rand(3,3), ones(2,2), 'uni', 0);

% Display it
celldisp(D)
```

Another possible way to display this is to create a custom little routine to print the data.

```
formatspec = '%10.4f';

format = repmat([repmat([formatspec ' '], [1 size(D{1},2)]), '    '], [1 size(D,2)]);
arrayfun(@(k)fprintf('%s\n', sprintf([format, '\n'], cat(2, D{k,:}).')), 1:size(D,1))
```

A third option, if you really want to export to Excel, you will want to alter the `fprintf` statement to create a CSV file.

```
fid = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
% Create the format specifier for a row
format = repmat([repmat('%0.4f,', [1 size(D{1}, 2)]), ','], [1 size(D,2)]);
format(end-1:end) = ''; 

for k = 1:size(D, 1)
    fprintf(fid, [format '\n'], cat(2, D{k,:}).');

    % Create an empty row
    fprintf(fid, ',\n');
end

fclose(fid);
```

The result when loaded in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Celldisp is useful for a shorter list of data, however I have for now a cell array of dimensions 2 x 40, and numbers in each matrix is not actually an integer, they are some number between 0 and 1.

It would be best to print out the data as the way I've shown, so that we can track how matrices evolve: each new column is generated with a certain way from the previous row, with a matrix multiplication.

Comment: I need to somehow export this to Excel, or to a printable medium.

When I apply the 'arrayfun' routine, I get the result which is still in Matlab interface, and the data I'm working on is really not pleasent to the eye: there are many different numbers between 0 and 1. And the data itself has 40 columns.

How can I improve from here?

Comment: @BoraAtalay Change the output of the `fprintf` to a file and it will create a text file containing your data.

Comment: @BoraAtalay I have updated with an example writing this to a CSV file which can be loaded into excel

Comment: It looks like your routine is exactly what I was hoping for, however only in Matlab interface. What I did was, I added,

`fileID = fopen('D.txt','w');`

and then fprintf(fileID, ...)

however in the txt file the gaps are not there, and it still looks mashed up. I also tried to save it to xls file: same. 

How can I move through? Thank you!

Comment: @BoraAtalay Please see the last update I mentioned. Open the resulting CSV file in excel and it will display as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! Latest edit of yours completely did what I was hoping for!

Now I'll practice on the routine you provided so that I can nail down what's going on also.